# After converting from Hg to Git, how do I remove the Hg source control?

Tags: git, mercurial, windows-7-x64, tortoisehg

I converted from Hg Git per [this blog](https://helgeklein.com/blog/2015/06/converting-mercurial-repositories-to-git-on-windows/#comment-194456), which worked fine.

Now I have:

```
Code\
   -\.git
   -\.hg
```

I don't need the .hg repo anymore. Can I just to the following?

1. Delete the .hg folder
2. Uninstall Hg (and TortoiseHg)

Comment: You answered it yourself. You no longer need it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. `.hg` folder only contains information needed by mercurial, git doesn't need that for anything. Everything git needs is in `.git` folder.